# If I unwittingly buy a meal with ham in it, it is acceptable to give it to a non-Muslim friend?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, pork

Sometimes I buy a meal thinking it doesn't contain ham, but it turns out it does (e.g. fried rice).  In these cases, I've switched meals with a non-Muslim friend who doesn't mind eating pork.

**Question**: If I unwittingly buy a meal with ham in it, it is acceptable to give it to a non-Muslim friend?

It seems wasteful to just throw it away and buy another dish and it would be rude to just throw a meal away that I just asked for and someone just cooked.

On [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/islam/comments/35yza4/can_you_give_haram_food_to_non_muslims/?st=iwzpc5ok&sh=26749414), people seemed to think it was haram to do so, but it was uncertain.

Comment: My private solution is either eating the rest and leaving the pork or switching with a non-Muslim AFAIK there's no rule prohibiting this.

Comment: The hadith where Umar was given a silk shirt by Muhammad which Umar then gave to his kafir brother seems related.

Answer (score 3):

The disbelievers are commanded to stay away from pork as well, just as they have been commanded by Allah to follow the truth of Islam and all it's rulings. You as a Muslim are meant to guide those who are misguided, not offer them your mistakenly bought pork products.

> وتعاونوا على البر والتقوى ولا تعاونوا على الإثم والعدوان واتقوا الله
>   إن الله شديد العقاب  - ....Help you one another in Al­Birr and
>   At­Taqwa (virtue, righteousness and piety); **but do not help one
>   another in sin and transgression**. And fear Allâh. Verily, Allâh is
>   Severe in punishment. (5:2)

Answer (score 1):

don't eat the rest and leave the pork behind, pork is nagis and it would spread onto the sandwitch
yes it is harm to give someone haram food not matter is there muslim or not. so yeah just throw it away...read the label before u buy something.
if something says its "suitable for vergiatrian" your good to go. :D