# Is it haram to cook non-halal meat and serve it to a Christian?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, food, christianity, meat

Is it haram to cook non-halal meat and serve it to a Christian? Bearing in mind that you don’t eat it, but just cooking it and serve it.

Comment: I asked a similar question here [If I unwittingly buy a meal with ham in it, it is acceptable to give it to a non-Muslim friend?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36932/17163).  It might be different, depending on whether the meat is pork (etc.) or not.

Comment: If it meets the hygienic standards and is tasty, then it's okay. Especially if the Christian likes it. Enjoy your moments together and don't let domas spoil it for you.

Comment: A chicken is a chicken! I'd rather eat halal food and enjoy a meal with my Muslim friend than eat pork chops / non halal chicken alone. Safe to say I'm speaking on behalf of most Christians.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, selling haram things is definitely forbidden, so you cannot sell any food that is haram:

> I saw the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) sitting neat the Black stone (or at a corner of the Ka'bah). He said: He (the Prophet) raised his eyes towards the heaven, and laughed, and he said: May Allah curse the Jews! He said this three times. Allah declared unlawful for them the fats (of the animals which died a natural death); they sold them and they enjoyed the price they received for them. **When Allah declares eating of thing forbidden for the people, He declares it price also forbidden for them.** The version of Khalid b. 'Abd Allah al-Tahhan does not have the words "I saw". It has: "May Allah destroy the Jews!" ([Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/24/73))

Basically, if you can't eat it or use it you can't make money off of it.

In the case of giving the food for free, the laws of Allah apply to everyone regardless of whether they acknowledge it or not. So as muslims, we cannot help someone do a sin (eating haram is a sin). In fact we are supposed to do the opposite; we are supposed stop it from happening:

> “You (true believers in Islamic Monotheism, and real followers of Prophet Muhammad and his Sunnah) are the best of peoples ever raised up for mankind; you enjoin Al-Ma‘roof (i.e. Islamic Monotheism and all that Islam has ordained) and forbid Al‑Munkar (polytheism, disbelief and all that Islam has forbidden), and you believe in Allaah” (3:110)

Since we are supposed to forbid sin, obviously it is forbidden to actively help it happen (by giving someone haram food).

Comment: @Downvoter . Why did you downvote?

Comment: Yes, I get your point we shouldn’t push people to do more sins but to do the opposite. But what if those christians are people with autism and mental health. They absolutely don’t understand anything of what is surrounding them and you giving them support. At the end of the day they don’t get any sins from allah because they are not like us we understand and we are judge of our acts whereas they don’t. I also been told giving them chicken or meat is not haram because it doesn’t have anything harmful for the body is just the way we kill it is different. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Chamal . I see but that is a more specialized case that you should ask a different question about. Rules in extreme situations are many times different.

Comment: So in this situation does it apply as doing something haram ot not? I seriously don’t give meat or chicken if is not halal but sometimes the person needs to get a proper meal and if there is no alternative food then it gets hard to leave them hungry and they are vulnerable people.

Comment: @Charmal . Are you in a situation of extremity, or is it just  a matter of convenience

Comment: As in, it is too hard to get halal food so I will serve something not halal?

Comment: We are not in charge to buy food for them and also I’ve asked if they can get halal food for them to make it easy for us too cook chicken and meat but the answer was no. They saying is like someone is muslim and we buy a not halal meat just because we didn’t find a halal meat. This means not to respect their preference and religion. So it was hard to convince them! But after all I still don’t give no chicken and meat only fish!

Comment: I would say unless you are forced out of necessity (the autistic person might die of starvation and there is absolutely **noone else** who can feed them or you cannot make halal food yourself) you shouldn't do it. But, fish is fine. It is halal.

Comment: I can see is a bit hard to answer this question. I also struggle to find an answer I might ask an imam about this otherwise I will have to resign from the job. I can’t always provide them fish they have to have different meals too. This is just like eating the same meal everyday when allah is giving us alternative ingredients to cook.

Comment: @Chamal . Yes, I agree. You should see an imam as the matter is complicated.